# El parámetro del tipo table '@TablaVulkeo' debe tener un nombre de tipo válido

Tags: sql, asp.net, datatables, stored-procedure

Hola que tal tengo un problema al tratar de insertar mi datatable dentro de un sp

Codigo sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_PartidasGasto] 
@TablaVulkeo StandarTableWS READONLY
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO db_Interface_SANTEC.dbo.PartidasGasto_WS (ID_PartidaGastoWS,
    [ID Proyecto],
     [Importe Costo],
     [Importe Banco],
     [Clase de Coste],
    [Fecha de Proceso],
    Horas,
    [ID de Recurso],
    Proveedor,
    [Breve Descripcion],
    [Origen del Insumo],
    TipoRecurso,
    NombreRecurso,
    Perfil,
    NombreProyecto,
    Cliente,
    Tecnologia,
    idExcel
    ,Pais,
    MonedaOrigen
    ,ImportePeso,
    ProvsionReal)  
    SELECT 
    NEWID(),
    nc.[IDProyecto],
     nc.[ImporteCosto],
     nc.[ImporteBanco],
      nc.[ClaseCosto],
      nc.[FechaProceso],
       nc.[Horas],
       nc.[IDRecurso], 
       nc.[Proveedor],
     nc.[Descripcion],
     nc.[OrigenInsumo], 
     nc.[TipoRecurso],
      nc.[NombreRecurso],
      nc.[Perfil],
       nc.[NombreProyecto],
    nc.[Cliente],
     nc.[Tecnologia],
      nc.IdExcel
      ,Pais
      ,MonedaOrigen,
      ImportePeso
      ,ProvisionReal FROM @TablaVulkeo AS nc; 

END
```

Codigo de C#:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@TablaVulkeo", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured);
command.Parameters["@TablaVulkeo"].Value = listExcel;


command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Estructura de @TablaVulkeo:

```
Create type StandarTableWS as table (
IDProyecto varchar(100) null,
ImporteCosto float null,
ImporteBanco float null,
ClaseCosto varchar(100) null,
FechaProceso datetime null,
Horas int null,
IDRecurso varchar(100) null,
Proveedor varchar(100) null,
Enviado bit null,
Descripcion varchar(100) null,
FechaCorte datetime null,
OrigenInsumo varchar(100) null,
Transferido bit null,
TipoRecurso varchar(100) null,
NombreRecurso varchar(100) null,
Perfil varchar(100) null,
NombreProyecto varchar(100) null,
Cliente varchar(100) null,
Tecnologia varchar(100) null,
IdExcel int null,
ProvisionReal varchar(10) null,
Pais varchar(100) null,
MonedaOrigen varchar(100) null,
ImportePeso float null
)
```

Error:

```
   El parámetro del tipo table '@TablaVulkeo' debe tener un nombre de tipo válido.
```

Esta es la estructura del ListExcel:

```
DataTable dtUpload = new DataTable();
dtUpload.Columns.Add("IDProyecto", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("ImporteCosto", typeof(float));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("ImporteBanco", typeof(float));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("ClaseCosto", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("FechaProceso", typeof(DateTime));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Horas", typeof(int));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("IDRecurso", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Proveedor", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Enviado", typeof(Boolean));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Descripcion", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("FechaCorte", typeof(DateTime));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("OrigenInsumo", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Transferido", typeof(Boolean));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("TipoRecurso", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("NombreRecurso", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Perfil", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("NombreProyecto", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Cliente", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Tecnologia", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("IdExcel", typeof(int));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("ProvisionReal", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("Pais", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("MonedaOrigen", typeof(string));
dtUpload.Columns.Add("ImportePeso", typeof(float));
```

Comment: ¿qué es el tipo `StandarTableWS`? ¿qué tipo es `listExcel`? ¿son compatibles?, aparentemente, no.

Comment: @jachguate ya hice las modifciaciones y se supone que si deberian ser compatibles